# scope.apply is not working in Angular Event Handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest, angularjs-rootscope

I have a parent page `_jobs.html` which has a `ng-include`

```
<div id="jobs-details" ng-controller="JobsController as jobsCtrl">
        <container container-id="jobs-details-container-portlet" height="1000px" columns="12" css-class="base-container">
            <portlet label="Job chart" height="1000px" columnspan="12" css-class="summary-pie-chart sub-tab-nav">
                <div>
                    <div ng-if="jobsCtrl.showSummaryTab">
                        <div ng-include src="'src/jobs/templates/jobs-details-filters.html'">
                        </div>
                    </div>                                  
                </div>
```

in `jobsCtrl`, I am reading a value `selectedJobType` from `stateParams` and I am broadcasting it.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("stateObjJobTypeReceived",stateObj.selectedJobType);
```

Now, inside `jobs-details-filters.html` controller:

If I try to read the value and assign to a variable like:

```
    $rootScope.$on("stateObjJobTypeReceived",function(event,_eventData) {    
            $timeout(function() {
                self.jobTypeSettings.selectedData = {"JobType_1": Array(0)};
                $scope.$apply();
            },0);                  
    });
```

It does not work.

But if I simply do **for testing purpose** without putting inside an event handler,

```
            $timeout(function() {
                self.jobTypeSettings.selectedData = {"JobType_1": Array(0)};
                $scope.$apply();
            },5000);
```

**it works. Value changes after 5 seconds**

Inside, event listener it seems not to work.

Basically I am trying to pass the value from `jobsCtrl` and assign accordingly to a variable and rootscope broadcast seems to me an only way.

Please help.

Comment: maybe `self` is not the same thing in your testing-purposes-code?

Comment: Broadcast should not be the only way, you can share the data via service, which is a better way.

Comment: What means "does not work"? And btw you never need $scope.$apply in $timeout